# Unity resources folder and loading next texture on 3D object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First of all I'm not a professional coder but have done some C# in the past. I have problem with my Unity project at the moment. I'm loading images from my resources folder and rendering them on a 3D object. Problem is with my nex texture "buttons" which are supposed to look at variable "n" and determinate which image is loaded as texture on a 3D object based on their order in the images folder. Currently when I click on a next image button it renders the next texture but only for the first 2 images in the folder. After that it does go in to the loop I've checked with debug.log but it does not render next image as a texture. Code is as following:

For the next button (that calls render texture and changes variable 'n' value):

```
void OnMouseDown() {
    if (this.name == "NextTexture") {
    LevelSelect.n=+2;
    LevelSelect.RenderTextures();

    }
    if (this.name == "PreviousTexture") {
    LevelSelect.n-=2;
    LevelSelect.RenderTextures();
    }
```

and for the image to texture rendering:

```
public static void RenderTextures(){

    Mesh mesh = staticMeshFilter.mesh;
    Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
    Vector2[] uvs = new Vector2[vertices.Length];

    for (int i=0; i < uvs.Length; i++) {
        uvs[i] = new Vector2(vertices[i].x, vertices[i].y);

    }
    mesh.uv = uvs;
    rend.material.mainTexture = loader.LoadImages ("images") [n];

    transformTexture.renderer.material.mainTextureOffset = new Vector2(0.4f, 0.28f); // +0.1x
    transformTexture.renderer.material.mainTextureScale = new Vector2(0.8f, 0.8f);


}
```

So at the moment I'm confused about how and why my code doesn't render the 3rd and 4th image from the images folder as textures.

Cheers!